# Is it possible for Apple-hosted content (purchased in-app) to be download piecemeal?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, ios7

I am working on a 'free' iOS app that will allow a user to buy a "pack" of 30 video files using in-app purchasing. E.g. they would pay 99¢ and get all 30 videos. Each video file averages 5MB in size.

I am considering whether or not to try and use Apple's content hosting for this in-app purchase. Is there any way for my app to download each video file (from Apple's hosted content area) only as the user wants to play each video? Rather than downloading the entire 150MB folder of videos all at one time, I could then just request a video file from this hosted content from Apple as I need it. Possible?

I'm also considering an option for the user to buy the videos in HD, which would increase the total file size even further. I doubt anyone wants to sit around while their iOS app downloads 500MB of videos at once, many of which they may not ever watch individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Apple don't cater for this scenario. You'd need to host the content yourself.